# Exception during dictionary initialization

Tags: c#, wcf, exception

I'm getting a type initialization error when trying to invoke a method from WCF service.

> The type initializer for 'X.Y.Z.AuditService' threw an exception.

However, I cannot see anything in the code which would cause the exception.

```
public enum AuditProcessType
{
    Facility,
    Patient,
    Report,
}


[ServiceBehavior(Name = "AuditService",
    Namespace = "http://xyz/services/2008/08",
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession,
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
public class AuditService : IAuditServiceContract
{
    private static Dictionary<AuditProcessType, Func<IAuditor>> auditServiceFactories;

    static AuditService()
    {
        auditServiceFactories = new Dictionary<AuditProcessType, Func<IAuditor>>()
        {
            { AuditProcessType.Facility, () => Auditor<Facility>.Instance },
            { AuditProcessType.Patient, () => Auditor<Patient>.Instance },
            { AuditProcessType.Report, () => Auditor<Report>.Instance },
        };
    }

    // ...

    private static IAuditor GetAuditor(AuditProcessType process)
    {
        Func<IAuditor> factory;
        if (!auditServiceFactories.TryGetValue(process, out factory) || factory == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(..., "process");
        }

        IAuditor auditor = null;
        try
        {
            auditor = factory();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(..., ex);
        }

        if (auditor == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(...);
        }

        return auditor;
    }
}

public class Auditor<T> : IAuditor
{
    private static Auditor<T> _instance = new Auditor<T>();

    public static Auditor<T> Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private Auditor()
    {
    }

    // ...
}
```

My logging framework does not show any inner exception details, so I can't get more information than this. No matter what I've tried, I can't seem to get the VS debugger to stop inside the type initializer. Still, I don't see how this code is raising an exception. My code by itself does nothing but initialize the factories dictionary, it doesn't even invoke `AuditService<T>.Instance`. What else could be causing this?

Comment: for details you can put code of "Auditor<Facility>.Instance" property into try catch block. Also switchou some properties in debuger posible helps.

Comment: On `AuditService`, do you have a non-static constructor, too?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth No, I don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked this down to an assembly load error. `IAuditor` is defined in a separate assembly from the `AuditService`, and because of issues during deployment, the `IAuditor` interface's assembly properly wasn't included in the application's bin directory. It was giving me an error during type initialization, because that was the point where the assembly load was occurring.

Answer (score 0):

In order for a type initializer to fail it must execute some code - and that code must fail. Looking at what you have posted, the only piece of executable code is here:

```
{ ... , () => Auditor<Facility>.Instance },
{ ... , () => Auditor<Patient>.Instance },
{ ... , () => Auditor<Report>.Instance },
```

Change your lambdas to

```
() => { 
    try { return Auditor<Facility>.Instance;  } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { System.Diagnostics.WriteLine(ex.Message); } 
}
```

and see if that doesn't catch some sort of error.

Comment: The lambdas aren't executed.

Comment: Yeah, hmm. I wonder then, has he instantiating an empty dictionary?

Comment: My code creates a dictionary of factory methods (as lambda expressions). I create each `IAuditor` on demand within my service methods. I actually do wrap each factory method in a try-catch to be safe, but that's done in a separate method named `GetAuditor`. I included the implementation of that method in the question for reference.

Comment: If you're referring to the `.svc` file, it's pretty trivial: `<%@ServiceHost language="c#" Debug="true" Service="X.Y.Z.AuditService" %>`

Comment: When is GetAuditor used? Also, do you have any other static fields in your AuditService class?

Comment: I have no other static members. `GetAuditor` is only used instance methods such as `var auditor = GetAuditor(...); auditor.ClearAuditHistory();`

Comment: Yeah, at this point you may need to just start commenting things out until you isolate what the issue is. Sorry can't help more than that at this point. Your code does look fine as you've presented it though.